# MySQL stored procedure returns multiple records while straight query returns one

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, uuid

If I create this stored procedure below and the run it I get back both rows from the table when it should be just one query.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `getUserName`(IN Guid VARCHAR(36), IN GameID INT(11))  
    BEGIN  
        SELECT `Name` as UserName, `GUID` as guid  
        FROM playerdata  
        WHERE `GUID` = Guid AND `GameID` = GameID;  
    END

    CALL getUserName('86fd1007-4a9c-11e7-b2e2-1803733c2d41', 1001);
```

Returns See Image

However if I just run it as a regular query

```
    SELECT `Name` as UserName, `GUID` as guid
    FROM playerdata
    WHERE `GUID` = "86fd1007-4a9c-11e7-b2e2-1803733c2d41" AND `GameID` = 1001;
```

Returns See Image

[image: Table Data and Query Results]

I am baffled as to the behavior considering... at least to me they are the same thing.

Comment: Rename stored procedure parameters, for example `_Guid` and `_GameID`. See [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs::Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Comment: \`GUID\` and Guid are the same thing. It's the same as 1=1.

Comment: Well that explains it. I keep forgetting when I switch in to SQL that it is case insensitive on most things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getUserName`(IN IN_Guid VARCHAR(36), IN IN_GameID INT(11))  
    BEGIN  
        SELECT `Name` as UserName, `GUID` as guid  
        FROM playerdata  
        WHERE `GUID` = IN_Guid  AND `GameID` = IN_GameID ;  
    END

    CALL getUserName('86fd1007-4a9c-11e7-b2e2-1803733c2d41', 1001);
```

Try above code.

If input parameter have same name as column name,it will finally evaluate equivalent to `1=1` so there is no meaning of condition.Means `GameID = GameID` and `1=1` both are equivalent.
So always try to make input and output parameters name differ to Column name of specific table.

I had tried it's working fine.

Hope this will helps you.